# retrieve how many node belongs to a taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have follow taxomony has been set up:

```
accommodation
-backpacker
-guest
-holiday
```

and i have a content type called listing which is connected with accommodation taxomony,
whenever i add a listing, this listing is associated with a type of accommodation.

now i need to find out how many listings under each taxomony.

for example: if i have set up 3 backpackers, 2 guests, 1 holiday, 
for accommodation i need a answer 6, for backpacker 3 etc.

is there a drupal funciton for this kind of calculation?

i am use drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`taxonomy_term_count_nodes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/taxonomy_term_count_nodes/6) for the basic version (counts only *published* nodes for exactly one term), and at [`taxonomy_select_nodes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6) if you need more flexibility in your counting (e.g. include depth, combine several terms, etc.).